# Wave Equation BC's

Tags: wave-equation

So, I'm trying to solve the wave equation with the Fourier transform, and I'm struggling to figure out how to apply the BC's.  Here's the problem I considered:

$$\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}=c^2\frac{d^2u}{x^2}$$
$$u(x,0)=g(x)$$
$$\frac{du}{dt}=0$$ at t = 0

Running through computations, I find that the Fourier transform solution is as follows:

$$F(u(\lambda,t))=A(\lambda)e^{ic\lambda t}+B(\lambda)e^{-ic \lambda t}$$

How would I apply boundary conditions to this and then transform back to u?  ANy detailed explanation on this would be appreciated (I'm still learning this stuff).  I'm thinking it may be easier to work with cosines and sines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically fourier the initial condition to get:

$\hat{u}(\lambda,0)=\hat{g}(\lambda)=A(\lambda)+B(\lambda)\Rightarrow A(\lambda)=\hat{g}(\lambda)-B(\lambda)$

$\frac{\partial\hat{u}}{\partial t}=ic\lambda A(\lambda)e^{ic\lambda t}-ic\lambda B(\lambda)e^{-ic\lambda t}=0\Rightarrow A(\lambda)=B(\lambda)e^{-2ic\lambda t}$

$\Rightarrow \hat{g}(\lambda)-B(\lambda)=B(\lambda)e^{-2ic\lambda t}\Rightarrow B(\lambda)=\large\frac{\hat{g}(\lambda)}{(1+e^{-2ic\lambda t})}$

$\Rightarrow A(\lambda)=\large\hat{g}(\lambda)-\frac{\hat{g}(\lambda)}{(1+e^{-2ic\lambda t})}$

Thus $\large\hat{u}(\lambda,t)=(\hat{g}(\lambda)-\frac{\hat{g}(\lambda)}{(1+e^{-2ic\lambda t})})e^{ic\lambda t}+(\frac{\hat{g}(\lambda)}{(1+e^{-2ic\lambda t})})e^{-ic\lambda t}$

$\large=\frac{e^{-ic\lambda t}}{1+e^{-2ic\lambda t}}+(\frac{\hat{g}(\lambda)}{(1+e^{-2ic\lambda t})})e^{-ic\lambda t}=\frac{1+\hat{g}(\lambda)e^{-ic\lambda t}}{1+e^{-2ic\lambda t}}$

Now you inverse fourier to find $u(x,t)$

Hope that helps.

Inverse fourier: (you are correct, this seems hard)

Write $\large\frac{1+\hat{g}(\lambda)e^{-ic\lambda t}}{1+e^{-2ic\lambda t}}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-2ic\lambda t}}+\frac{\hat{g}(\lambda)e^{-ic\lambda t}}{1+e^{-2ic\lambda t}}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-2ic\lambda t}}+\hat{g}(\lambda)\hat{f}(\lambda,t)$

Then $u(x,t)=F^{-1}(\frac{1}{1+e^{-2ic\lambda t}})+(\sqrt{2\pi})g(x)f(x,t)$

This simplifies things, so you need to calculate:

$\large F^{-1}(\frac{1}{1+e^{-2ic\lambda t}})$, and $\large F^{-1}(\frac{e^{-ic\lambda t}}{1+e^{-2ic\lambda t}})$

Comment: Thank you for repsonse.  That was very helpful, but I think we'd have a lot of trouble inversting that transform.  How would you go about performing a Fourier inverse on that?  Wouldn't that integral be unsolvable?

Comment: I've put in an edit that should help you to get closer, but the integration seems difficult.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{{\rm u}\pars{x,t} = \fermi\pars{x - ct} + {\rm h}\pars{x + ct}}$ is a *general solution*.

> \begin{align}
> \left.\partiald{{\rm u}\pars{x,t}}{t}\right\vert_{t\ =\ 0} = 0\quad\imp\quad 0=-c\fermi'\pars{x} + c{\rm h}'\pars{x}\quad\imp\quad{\rm h}\pars{x} = f\pars{x} + A\,,\quad A\ \mbox{is a constant}
> \end{align}

Then, $\ds{{\rm u}\pars{x,t} = \fermi\pars{x - ct} + \fermi\pars{x + ct} + A}$

> $$
> {\rm u}\pars{x,0} = {\rm g}\pars{x}\quad\imp\quad
> 2\fermi\pars{x} + A = {\rm g}\pars{x}\quad\imp\quad\fermi\pars{x}
> = {{\rm g}\pars{x} - A \over 2}
> $$

$$
{\rm u}\pars{x,t}={{\rm g}\pars{x - ct} - A \over 2}
+{{\rm g}\pars{x + ct} - A \over 2} + A
$$

> $$\color{#00f}{\large%
> {\rm u}\pars{x,t} = \half\,\bracks{{\rm g}\pars{x - ct} + {\rm g}\pars{x + ct}}}
> $$